# Adding 'timex v3.7' fails Phoenix service to start for 'parse_trans_codegen'

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

Reason:

I was missing `erlang-syntax_tools` package.

When I try it on a container, there is no issue... will close the issue.

I'm using latest package, will re-install or just use container for the while.

---

**Steps to reproduce**

- when I add {:timex, "~> 3.7"} to [a new Phoenix project](https://github.com/abhishekkr/calendo) created for learning and try start service with `mix deps.get && iex -S mix phx.server`, it fails with following errors...

```
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.3.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling parse_trans
===> Compiling src/exprecs.erl failed
src/exprecs.erl:none: error in parse transform 'parse_trans_codegen':
exception error: undefined function erl_syntax:string/1
  in function  parse_trans:get_file/1 (LOCAL_PATH/calendo/deps/parse_trans/src/parse_trans.erl, line 227)
  in call from parse_trans:initial_context/2 (/LOCAL_PATH/calendo/deps/parse_trans/src/parse_trans.erl, line 299)
  in call from parse_trans_codegen:parse_transform/2 (LOCAL_PATH/calendo/deps/parse_trans/src/parse_trans_codegen.erl, line 147)
  in call from compile:foldl_transform/3 (compile.erl, line 1147)
  in call from compile:fold_comp/4 (compile.erl, line 418)
  in call from compile:internal_comp/5 (compile.erl, line 402)
  in call from compile:'-internal_fun/2-anonymous-0-'/2 (compile.erl, line 229)
```

> even doing mix deps.compile prase_trans or deps.clean & deps.get fails

My local setup is **OTP 24, Elixir 1.13.4, Phoenix 1.6.10, rebar 3.19.0, Erts 12.3.2.1** and entire [app code is here](https://github.com/abhishekkr/calendo). Just adding `timex` dependency to it and starting service causes this issue.

**Description of issue**

The error occur as soon I add `timex` dep to mix and run service without any extra code. So it gets introduced by one of the constructs from it.
The error is weird since `erl_syntax:string/1` seems to be a valid call which gets notified as undefined in error stack.

Comment: Dunno if this could help, but recently I had a weird error compiling some erlang dependency that I couldn't fix by `deps.clean` or any other way, and finally running `mix local.rebar` fixed it.

Comment: @sabiwara I did try that...
I also tried doing an install in `deps/parse_trans` with `~/.mix/rebar3 compile` which resulted in same error

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with the erlang install itself? As you pointed out, `erl_syntax:string/1` should exist, it is a really weird error.

Comment: when I try it on a container, there is no issue... will close the issue

Comment: How did you install Erlang/Elixir?

Comment: @Everett it was using system package manager `dnf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing package `erlang-syntax_tools` fixed the issue with parse_trans required in `timex`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this was just a typo on OP's part, but on my system (ubuntu 22.04 after adding the ppa:rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang apt repository as per the elixir install instructions) I needed to install `erlang-syntax-tools`